# .NET Use A Related Table To Decide What Information to Show

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a client model a identifier model and a link model. The identifier model contains websites available for posting, client model contains clients that need a specific amount of links per month. A link object in the link model contains the Identifier ID and the Client ID. I want another view displaying a table of all the Identifier ID's that haven't been used with a Client ID's in the Link model table if this makes sense?

Client Model:

```
namespace Linkofy.Models
{
    public class Client
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Client")]
    public string clientN { get; set; }

    [Url]
    [Display(Name = "Website")]
    public string homePage{ get; set; }

    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Contact Email")]
    public string clientEmail { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Contact Name")]
    public string contName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Monthly")]
    public int monthlyQuota { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "TF")]
    public int TrustFlow { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "CF")]
    public int CitationFlow { get; set; }

    public int RI { get; set; }

    public int? MJTopicsID { get; set; }
    public virtual MJTopics MJTopics { get; set; }

    public int UserTableID { get; set; }
    public virtual UserTable UserTable { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Link> Links { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Status> Statuss { get; set; }
}
}
```

Link Model:

```
namespace Linkofy.Models
{
public class Link
{
    public int LinkID { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Linking Page")]
    public string Obdomain { get; set; }


    public int? ClientID { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Outbound Link")]
    public string Obpage { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Anchor Text")]
    public string Anchor { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Date Built")]
    public DateTime BuildDate { get; set; }

    public int IdentifierID { get; set; }
    public virtual Identifier Identifier { get; set; }

    public int? UserTableID { get; set; }
    public virtual UserTable UserTable { get; set; }

}
 }
```

Domain Model:

```
public class Identifier
{
public enum Ltype
    {
        GuestPost, ExistingLink
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Url]
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Domain")]
    public string domain { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Contact Email")]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string contact { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Contact Name")]
    public string contactname { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Price")]
    public int price { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Type of Link")]
    public Ltype? type { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "TF")]
    public int TrustFlow { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "CF")]
    public int CitationFlow { get; set; }

    public int RI { get; set; }

    public int? MJTopicsID { get; set; }
    public virtual MJTopics MJTopics { get; set; }

    public virtual UserTable UserTable { get; set; }
    public int UserTableID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Link> Links { get; set; }
}
}
```

Model View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Linkofy.Models.Identifier>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@section Styles {
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Styles/Index.css")" rel="stylesheet"     type="text/css" />
}

<h1>Domain List</h1>

  <p class="options"> @Html.ActionLink("Add New", "Create")   |   @Html.ActionLink("Add Bulk", "CreateBulk") </p>

   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.domain)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.contact)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.contactname)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.price)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.type)
    </th>
            <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TrustFlow)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CitationFlow)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RI)
    </th>
            <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MJTopics.topicalTF)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.Where(Model.Links.Item => item.ClientID != ViewBag.ClientID)) {
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.domain)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.contact)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.contactname)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.price)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.type)
    </td>
            <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TrustFlow)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CitationFlow)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RI)
    </td>
            <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MJTopics.topicalTF)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Details", new { id=item.ID }, new {@class= "glyphicon glyphicon-home" })
        @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }, new {@class= "glyphicon glyphicon-edit" }) 
        @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Delete", new { id=item.ID }, new {@class= "glyphicon glyphicon-trash" })
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
                            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, how are you getting this data? How are you displaying this data in the `View`? Are they `ICollection<Client>`? What do you mean by `Domain ID's`? I see no `Domain` Model class!

Comment: @Mahmoud quite right sorry! even explaining it confuses me, I wrote it as domains as I wasn't going to post the models and it would make more sense to someone with some SEO knowledge. I will update the question to incorporate your points, thanks!

Comment: So basically what you want is to filter your list, perhaps you should use Lambda to narrow that down, is that what you don't know how to do?

Comment: @Zorkind well I had been trying to think of many ideas but came to nothing as I'm still quite fresh in this! But if that sounds like something that would achieve what I'm trying to do then yeah that would be awesome been at it for a couple days :)

Comment: Ok, but how do you feed your views with data now?

Comment: @Zorkind The same way EF6 creates them with the index view returning the database to list and the details view passing an ID number of the chosen object. So my idea was to pass a client ID into a view since that would be static for what I'm trying to do though I'm unsure

Comment: Well, lets summarize all you will have to do, sorry if i am taking this to low key levels. You need create a custom Action in your Controller class, call it what you want "ClientsWithoutIdentifier" then inside that method, you will need to return a custom view, with the same name so you don't have to specify it, and a filtered list using Linq queries, so you can specify the data you want to return. My question to you in all these steps is: what part of this you are having a problem?

Comment: @not a problem I appreciate the help. Would this be in the identifier controller class then? I've just never heard of Linq queries is all and have no experience with them so didn't know them as an option I shall look into them and let you know!

Comment: All good, yes well EF is made around Linq, so you better go read some materials on that, it will make your life easier and there are quite a lot of good materials on that. Perhaps watch a full video about Entity Framework and MVC, it will help you a lot.

Comment: @Zorkind Feel like I want something like this: 
 foreach (var item in Model.Where(var item in Model.Links.ClientID != ViewBag.ClientID) {

though I just can't grasp the logic behind it, does this make sense?

Comment: @liamcook yes it makes sense, it's as i suspected then. You are in the right path, keep learning, i feel like an answer to what you need is not going to be enough, you need to learn this in detail. Here is not the best place.

Comment: @Zorkind so i've been having a go and still can't seem to figure it out, I wonder if you could point me in the right direction, I've put in 3 examples at the end of the question that i've had a go and their errors, would be masively appreciated, thanks!

Comment: well, there's no `var item` there's `item =>` instead.

Comment: that comma exception is probably in some other line of your code.

Comment: @zorkind ahh I see, even tho an identifierid may appear in the link table multiple times as it's an collection can i still use item =>? Thanks For your time !

Comment: you are not using the `=>` in the foreach, but in the `Where()` extension method

Comment: well you can name that something else... like `i` instead

Comment: the point is.... you can't use `var` in an expression, perhaps you should read   [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) about expressions

Comment: @Zorkind the original var item in model expression was created by EF and works to display the list, ive used it with simple lamda expressions before and it works but only when one table was involved :/

Comment: Inside the Where Method? this makes zero sense :-\ the var in the foreach is ok.

Comment: @zorkind no you're right I really just can't understand the logic in it whatsoever. I've read the articles on lambda expressions though I just can't understand the logic I need :/// thanks for sticking around this long though!! This is as close as ive got but I just get the comma error = foreach (var item in Model.Where(Model.Links.Item => item.Client.ID != ViewBag.ClientID)) { or foreach (var item in Model.Where(c => c.Links.ClientID != ViewBag.ClientID)) { but both return the syntax error comma expected ://

Comment: I am sure the error is somewhere else in the code, it shows you that line cause it's probably the closer he can get. since you coding in the View, there's html all around, so make sure there's no comma some where.

Comment: @zorkind I tried the expressions in my other view which works and it returned the same error not sure if its to do with referencing two tables?

Comment: need to see more code to understand what's going on @liamcook i can't figure it out with just 1 line.

Comment: @zorkind I added my model view to the question its pretty simple, though I cant see any issues with it :/ Thanks

Comment: Instead of `Model.Links.Item` just type `item`

Comment: i would suggest to use a diff name tho like `_item` inside the `Where()`

Comment: @zorkind but then how will it know that I am asking it to look through the links table opposed to the identifier table?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162829/discussion-between-zorkind-and-liamcook).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this using LINQ statements as mentioned by Zorkind in comments.